Why is there suddenly a lock logo on image files and folders in Windows Explorer so they can't be accessed?
I just repaired my laptop which had been damaged for years, after it was finished and could be turned on, I moved the data to the new laptop, but suddenly every folder and file appeared as follows and could not be accessed.
I'm very confused, what should I do?

And now, when I want to move from this hard disk to another hard disk, I get a warning "do you want to copy this folder without encryption?" A problem is preventing this folder from being encrypted"
What is meant by encryption? because as far as I remember I never gave an encryption.


What mechanism did you use to move the data?

I just use ctrl+x and ctrl+v from the laptop to the hard disk as an intermediary, I don't know what causes it to be inaccessible

Did you move it through the old OS or the new OS? Were the files still accessible in the old OS? (More importantly, do you still have the old OS available?)

I moved it from the old OS on the old laptop (Windows 10) to the new laptop (Windows 11). and my old laptop has been reinstalled.

You are either missing permissions to the files, which you can give yourself if you are a local administrator, or the files were encrypted, meaning only the original Windows user account can decrypt and read them.
See "How to get rid of the lock symbols on files which denies access when opened?"
